# reledmac: empty entry in endnote-apparatus using \ledsidenote + \edtabular

Tags: tables, endnotes, reledmac

I use `\doendnotesbysection{X}` and encountered a problem using an `\Xendnote` in an `\edtabular`-environment **and** a `\ledsidenote` in the same section:
There appear empty entries in the endnote-apparatus.

Here the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\linenummargin{inner} 
\sidenotemargin{outer} 

\let\Bfootnoterule=\relax
\Xnotenumfont[B]{\bfseries}
\Xendnotenumfont[B]{\bfseries}
\Xendparagraph[B]
\Xendbeforepagenumber[B]{}
\Xendafterpagenumber[B]{}
\Xendlemmaseparator[B]{\rbracket}
\renewcommand*{\printnpnum}[1]{} % Keine Seitenzahlen in Endnotes
\Xtwolines[B]{f.}
\Xtwolinesbutnotmore[B]
\Xendtwolines[B]{f.}
\Xendtwolinesbutnotmore[B]


\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Example} % it's a subsubsection to simulate my original document.
\beginnumbering
\pstart\noindent
\ledsidenote{[52r]}%
    Figura testimoniorum planetarum in 12 domibus eorum, quantas habeant uirtutes, quilibet in qualibet.
\pend
\bigskip
\pstart
    \begin{center}
        \begin{edtabularl}
            Pro domo & & 52 & \\
            Pro exaltatione & & 43 & \\
            Pro triplicitate & & 34 & 
            \edtext{Ptolemaei}{
                \Bfootnote{Ptolomei}} \\
            Pro termino & & 21 & \\
            Pro facie & \edatright[\text{Habent testimonia}]{\}}{2.5\baselineskip} \edatleft[]{\{}{2.5\baselineskip} & 1 &
        \end{edtabularl}
    \end{center}
\pend
\endnumbering

\doendnotesbysection{B}
\end{document}
```

It may not be super minimal, but I tried to reconstruct the appearance that I actually use in my original document.

If you delete the `\ledsidenote`, the endnote shows up totally fine. Also, if you use `\Xfootnote`, it works, too, but I need endnotes and `\ledsidenote`.

Is there a way to get around this problem using endnotes and `\ledsidenote` anyway?

Comment: Are there no comments/answers because it's too complex or because it's too trivial? I'd appreciate any help and suggestions.

Comment: Because not a lot of people use reledmac/reledpar, and because my computer is broken, so I don't look everyday on new reledmac topic on SE. I am looking on your problem.

Comment: I have tried your example., and I can have both ledsidenote and endnote. Cf https://www.overleaf.com/read/gdjzhbmjhzgz

Comment: Yes, there is no error. But there are two "empty" endnotes ("1 ] Ptolomei") and one correct ("5 Ptolemaei] Ptolomei"), although there should only be only the one correct. When deleting the \ledsidenote or changing the endnote to a footnote, only the correct one appears. But I need both: the endnote and the ledsidenote. So, my question is: Is there a way to have these both, without the "empty" endnotes?

Comment: That is a bug. Please open an issue on github. I will look on it as soon as will get a working computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug (which was not directly related to sidenotes) has been fixed on reledmac 2.24.2, just send on CTAN.